# Countif only if it exists for one particular criteria for only the first instance

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am stuck with something that I feel like should be relatively simple.

I am trying to create a count column that only counts the IDs that are only classified with DC, and only counts it for the first instance.

Expected outcome:

[image]

So far what I thought of was to create an unique ID in order to only count the first instance:

[image]

I tried the following formula but it's not correct as it cannot correctly identify only the cells that fit my criteria.

=IF(A2=A1,0,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,C2:C7="DC"))

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like your formula excludes the unique ID column. Shouldn't you be referencing column `B` somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear on several aspects, for example the first and last rows match the criteria you mentioned (classified as DC and first instance).  In addition the count is showing "1", where there are 2 x "DC" instances in the ID? Would assume this is sorted in Key order.   So with that...

The trick is to work out the cell in which the first instance that the criteria occurs within, and then execute the count.

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A$2:A$7,A2)>1,COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1),COUNTIF(A$2:A$7,A2)-1,0)
```

This IF statement checks if the key appears more than once, AND if it is the first occurrence of the key. If these are both true, then execute the count.  I have assumed you don't want to count the first instance (hence the -1), so keep or remove that if it makes sense.  Please take careful note of the absolute references, particularly in the second COUNTIF which only counts down to the current row (A2).

Update.

With the comments below, if you are only looking to mark the row, then the following will show a true/false that takes into account your updated criteria. If you need more, use this as the basis for an "IF" statement.

```
=AND(COUNTIF(B$2:B$7,B2)=COUNTIF(A$2:A$7,A2),COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1)
```

Comment: Hi Davo - appreciate the help - and my apologies for not stating the question in a better way. This formula does not do exactly what I want. What I am trying to accomplish is to mark only the first instance of anything that is exclusively only in DC (hence why in my example only one row is marked with a 1). For example, in my example ID 1354 is in both ECOM/DC - so it should be marked as 0. However, 2214 is only in DC and only the first instance is marked as 1.

Comment: If you are only looking to mark the row, then the following will show a true/false that takes into account your updated criteria.


 =AND(COUNTIF(B$2:B$7,B2)=COUNTIF(A$2:A$7,A2),COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1)

Comment: Thanks Davo, that seems to do the trick, appreciate the help and time invested.